# Import project from git in xcode

Tags: xcode, git

I have a project under source control with at remote repository where I commit and push to.

Now I need to have another programmer work on the same project and therefore same Git repo.

I cannot figure out how one imports a project from an existing Git repo.

I have worked with Eclipse and Git where I have no problem doing this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**For xCode 6 and lower**

In xCode go to Window >> Organiser

Then select repositories

Click the + button and select Checkout or Clone repository

Then enter the details for your GIT

**For xCode7 and above**

Go to Window >> Welcome to xCode

Click on the **Check out an existing project** button on the left hand side.

Then enter the details for the repository you want to access.

Comment: That simple! Thank you!

Comment: As of Xcode 7 repositories does not appear under Organiser. You can use Window>>Welcome to Xcode instead.

Answer (score 6):

For Xcode 9.4 and Git repository without `*.xproj` file simple *Source Control -> Clone...* method doesn't work. Xcode just clones remote repository and opens it in Finder - no project is created nor opened.

---

Here is what worked for my remote C++ repository:

1. `$ git clone [your_repo.git]`
2. Create new project **Shift + CMD + N**
3. Enable version control

   [image: version control]
4. Now you should have cloned repo and new Xcode repo:

   [image: new repo]
5. In your new Xcode repo remove all except *.xcodeproj
6. In Xcode remove default Groups and Files (except Products):

   [image: remove default groups and files]
7. Copy cloned repo content into new Xcode project directory:

   `$ ditto [cloned_repo/] [new_repo/]`.

   Check that `.git` directory was copied successfully.
8. Add dirs and files into the project. Drag'n'drop them from Finder to your new Xcode project. Don't drag `.git` and `*.xcodeproj`.

   [image: drag'n'drop]

   [image: references]
9. Check branches and commit history:

   [image: check version control history]

Answer (score 3):

Since the answers are old, now there's an easier way to directly **import/clone** project into Xcode from Github and Bitbucket.

**Bitbucket:** Press *Clone in Xcode* button
[image]

**Github:** Press *Open in Xcode* button
[image]

Comment: Note that this only works if it's already an Xcode project. https://github.blog/2017-06-05-clone-in-xcode/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that now (Version 12.0.1) there is no "officially supported" way to work with source control at Xcode with repository without *.xcodeproj file

Comment: Yes you can. See the top voted answer, the section titled "For xCode 7 and above." What I'm seeing is that it'll clone the repo but xCode's Project Navigator isn't populating with the folders since there isn't a project. At this point, you can navigate into that repo and do what you need to do (scripts perhaps) to generate your project. After that, open the project and you should be good to go.